# dynamic number of columns in a data table with unique random draws

Tags: r, random, data.table

Suppose I have the following matrix, for arbitrary J:

```
set.seed(1)
J=2
n = 100
BB = data.table(r=1:n)
BB[, (paste0("a",seq(J))) := rnorm(n,1,7) ]
```

So the output is...

```
> BB
       r           a1           a2
  1:   1  -3.38517668  -3.38517668
  2:   2   2.28550327   2.28550327
  3:   3  -4.84940029  -4.84940029
      ...
```

How come the two columns are identical and now different rnorms?

Comment: The columns are identical because you've called `rnorm(n,1,7)` *once* and assigned the return value to the `J` columns

Comment: Ok, but how do i call it multiple times then? That's essentially my question,    `temp1[,
          (paste0("a",seq(J))) := Map(
            function(n,m,s) rnorm(n,m,s),
            n,0,1)
          
]`

Does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the super-fast `for-set` combination:

```
for(i in seq(J))
    set(x = BB, j = paste0('a',i), value = rnorm(n, 1, 7))
```